# Derivation of posterior distribution, is it correct?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

Suppose that we have the following joint model, with $D$ the data and $m$ and $p$ parameters to be inferred.

$$f(D,m,p) = f(D|m,p)f(m|p)f(p)$$

my goal is to find the posterior distribution up to proportionality for the parameter $m$.

Based on the factorization of the joint distribution, I would assume that the posterior for the parameter $m$ would be

$$f(m|D,p) \propto f(D|m,p)f(m|p)$$

however, the likelihood $f(D|m,p)$ and the prior $f(m|p)$ share a term, i.e. the p.

---

Is it a problem that the likelihood and prior of $m$ share a parameter ??

Are the calculations correct, for deriving the posterior distribution??

Comment: It correct to say that $f(m|D,p)\propto f(D|m,p)f(m|p)$, yes. It's just like a classical Bayes formula, but conditionned on $p$ (which is okay to do).

Comment: @Pohoua So, there is no problem for the Likelihood $f(D|m,p)$ and prior $f(m|p)$ to share a parameter?? Because some people might argue that you considering your data twice because you include terms of the likelihood into your prior?

Comment: No, as long as it's not the parameter of interest. It's like considering the $p$ parameter to be fixed and not random.